# how to get blender cars,furnitures,trees etc free?

Tags: mesh

how to get blender cars,furnitures,trees etc free ? if you know any sites or links , then please answer me , am already try blender market , but i think thats must need money
then am post this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look to www.blendswap.com for donated assets - just be aware of the individual licenses involved